# WinJS template <p> not rendering

Tags: html, windows-8, tags, html-parsing, winjs

I am working on a Windows 8 application with HTML/JS.
I've got problem with the template rendering. The paragraph "row" does not render, only the h4 and h6. If I change the "p" to "h3" or "h4" etc. it works tho. 
I've also tried to change the data-win-bind property "innerText" to "text" and "textContent" without success.

I don't wanna have headings everywhere. Why doesn't it work? I have seen examples were people seems to use "p" without problems.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="detailedViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: DiareNumber" />
    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Company" />
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: Administrator" />
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting! Did you try <div>? I can't think of any reason why <p> should behave differently, as I've used all kinds of tags in my item templates.

Comment: I tried `<div>` as well and `<span>`. The problem was the self closing tag on the heading elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing I found out that the problem is the self-closing of tag for the heading tags `<h6>` and `<h4>`. It has to be closed properly, unless the parsing won't work as intended. **HTML5 does NOT allow "self-closing" tags on non-void elements.**

After some research I found this site explaining why:
http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

In this case `<p>` does not require an end tag if the p element is immediately followed by an *address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element*, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

**Solution**

So by changing:

```
<div id="detailedViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: DiareNumber" />
    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Company" />
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: Administrator" />
    ...
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="detailedViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: DiareNumber"></h4>
    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Company"></h6>
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: Administrator"></p> <!-- optional -->
    ...
</div>
```

and now it works without any problems!

Comment: won't the solution require all the 3 element h4 h6 and p to have end tags? in my trial - all of them need to be closed for it to work. pl check and update answer.

Comment: @Sushil oh yes of course, thank you! I edited the answer and it should now be correct.

Comment: pl add p also in the snippet

Comment: Just a side note, this is because HTML5 does not equate to XHTML5. In regular HTML self-closing tags are actually invalid although most browser engines will work around it and "fix" it for you.